# performance about url.parse in Nodejs

Tags: performance, node.js, siege

I just traced my nodejs server's performance by using: `siege -b -t10s -q http://mynodejsserver`

I found that when there was no "url.parse(req.url)"

Transaction rate was about 4300 trans/sec

but when i used url.parse, transaction rate was about 3600-3700 trans/sec

The other code is the same.

I tried them many times, and the result was stable.

Does the url.parse really have the performance problem?

Comment: This fixes the performance problem: https://npmjs.org/package/fast-url-parser . It has exactly same api and semantics but it is 25-30x faster and would not affect the transaction rate at all in your example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### YES

Yes, in the [techempower benchmarks](http://techempower.com/benchmarks/#section=data-r7&hw=i7&test=fortune) node.js went from 20k/s to 30k/s when removing `url.parse`.

The implementation is very slow like most node.js modules (I have rewritten 3x-75x speed improvements on several "de facto standard" node modules, just check my github profile).

I have actually planned a `url.parse` rewrite too. But yes, if you can avoid it then you should avoid it.

---

## Update

This fixes the performance problem: https://npmjs.org/package/fast-url-parser . It has exactly same api and semantics but it is 25-30x faster and would not affect the transaction rate at all in your example.

Comment: Is this still relevant in 2023, 10 years later?